# Is there a way to fix this problem "missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python

I'm trying to follow a youtube tutorial on making object detection software, link here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hVavSe60M3g&t=612s, and I'm not doing too well as 10 minutes in I've already found an issue, I added my own test videos to see if it works but when I run it it says missing one positional argument: 'self', I'm quite new to classes so I don't exactly know how they work, and if I'm making some dumb rookie error, but some help would be greatly appreciated. There are two programs and the TypeError, so I'll add those below:

Detector:

```
import cv2

import numpy as np 
import time

class Detector:
    def __init__(self, videoPath, configPath, modelPath, classesPath):
        self.videoPath = videoPath
        self.configPath = configPath
        self.modelPath = modelPath
        self.classesPath = classesPath

        #####################################

        self.net = cv2.dnn_DetectionModel(self.modelPath, self.configPath)
        self.net.setInputSize(320,320)
        self.net.setInputScale(1.0/127.5)
        self.net.setInputMean((127.5, 127.5, 127.5))
        self.net.setInputSwapRB(True)

        self.readClasses()

    def readClasses(self):
        with open(self.classesPath, 'r') as f:
            self.classesList = f.read().splitlines()

        self.classesList.insert(0, '__Background__')

        self.colorList = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=255, size=(len(self.classesList), 3))

        # print(self.classesList)

    def onVideo(self):
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(self.videoPath)

        if (cap.isOpened()==False):
            print("Error opening the file... ")
            return
        
        (success, image) = cap.read()

        while success:
            classLabelIDs, confidences, bboxs = self.net.detect(image, confThreshold = 0.4)

            bboxs = list(bboxs)
            confidences = list(np.arry(confidences).reshape(1,-1)[0])
            confidences = list(map(float, confidences))

            bboxIdx = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(bboxs, confidences, score_threshold = 0.5, nms_threshold = 0.2)

            if len(bboxIdx) != 0:
                for i in range(0, len(bboxIdx)):

                    bbox = bboxs[np.squeeze(bboxIdx[i])]
                    classConfidence = confidences[np.squeeze(bboxIdx[i])]
                    classLabelID = np.squeeze(classLabelIDs[np.squeeze(bboxIdx[i])])
                    classLabel = self.classesList[classLabelID]
                    classColor = [int(c) for c in self.colorList[classLabelID]]

                    displayText = "{}:{:.2f}".format(classLabel, classConfidence=1)
                    cv2.putText(image, displayText, (x, y-10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1, classColor, 2)

                    x,y,w,h = bbox

                    cv2.rectangle(image, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), color=classColor, thickness=1)

            cv2.imshow("Result", image)

            key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
            if key == ord("q"):
                break

            (success, image) = cap.read()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Main:

```
from Detector import *
import os

def main():
    videoPath = "test_videos/gamevid.mp4"

    configPath = os.path.join("model_data", "ssd_mobilenet_v3_large_coco_2020_01_14.pbtxt")
    modelPath = os.path.join("model_data", "frozen_inference_graph.pb")
    classesPath = os.path.join("model_data", "coco.names")

    Detector(videoPath, configPath, modelPath, classesPath)
    Detector.onVideo()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Error:

```
  File "c:\Users\mondo\Desktop\Final DT software\real_time_object_detection_cpu-main\model_data\DetectorMain.py", line 12, in main
    Detector.onVideo()
TypeError: onVideo() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'       
PS C:\Users\mondo\Desktop\Final DT software\real_time_object_detection_cpu-main>
```

Comment: When you use `Detector.onVideo` there's no _instance_ associated to become `self`. Whereas if you use `myDetector = Detector()` and then call `myDetector.onVideo()`, then `myDetector` becomes `self`.

Answer (score 3):

You created an instance of `Detector`, but you did not use it.

```
 d = Detector(videoPath, configPath, modelPath, classesPath)
 d.onVideo()
```

Due to how the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) works, `d.onVideo()` is equivalent to `Dectector.onVideo(d)`. When you called `Decector.onVideo()`, you did not supply the instance that the descriptor protocol would have supplied implicitly.